# Unity3 оптимизация проекта под WebGL

Tags: оптимизация, unity3d

Пишу проект, 3D игра. Нужно её компилировать под WebGL.
Возникает следующие вопросы:

1. Каким образом оптимально настроить все это добро перед компиляцией, какой `WebGL Memory Size` указывать? От чего отталкиваться при выборе этого параметра?
2. Существуют ли какие-то правила, по поводу ведения проекта? Мой проект весит сейчас около 7-8г.
3. Поскольку игра браузерная, как можно оптимизировать скорость загрузки в браузере?

Comment: в вашем вопросе содержится не один, а несколько вопросов. здесь же приветствуется схема «один вопрос — один (и более) ответ», и, главное, нет ограничений на количество задаваемых вопросов. конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо подумайте, прежде чем выбирать платформу Unity для веб-проектов в настоящий момент. WebGL для Unity еще очень сырая, особенно в том, что касается управления оперативной памятью. Фактически, если сцена занимает больше 200-300 мегабайт RAM, то вы столкнетесь с ошибкой превышения выделенной памяти и отказом приложения продолжать работу.

Использовать старый добрый Unity Web Player тоже стало проблематично с января 2015 года из за ограниченной поддержки NPAPI в последних версиях Chrome.

В связи с этим рекомендую посмотреть в сторону других движков. Недавно на Habrahabr была статья: ["Почему в NASA отказались от Unity в пользу Blend4Web"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/264457/), которая хорошо описывает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу оптимизаций, если актуально, на сколько я знаю в Unity есть

1) разбиение на чанки

2) ассеты включать в сборку только нужные, половину (скрипты редактора например и неиспользуеммые шейдеры ) исключить.

3) скрипты и прочее компилить в бинарные данные
Кроме того на сервер установить zip и настроить на хосте обработку скомпилированных ассетов как zip

4) памяти выделять в настройках сколько не жалко, с учётом того, что это вэб, т.е. приложение должно быть максимально клиентоориентированным, у одного человека 2гб оперативки и встроенная видеокарта, у другого 16гб и GTX750

Да и сам браузер жрёт не хило.

5) ну и неплохой оптимизацией будет правильное составление текстурных атласов